# What does it mean for something to be 'knocked out of its orbit'?

Tags: physics, astronomy

The idea of knocking a satellite out of its orbit is common in fiction, but what does it actually mean.

Answer (score 6):

Orbits are not like rails a train might run on where there's some threshold between staying on the exact same path or flying off in some catastrophic manner.

An orbit is just falling and missing the ground, or whatever you are falling toward.  If you are falling and a force pushes you, you will still be falling, just along a different path.

So any force acting on a satellite (be it a fleck of paint orbiting the Earth or a star orbiting the galactic barycentre) will change its path, even very very tiny forces, although the change will be comparatively small.

In simple cases where a satellite is orbiting a spherical object and other objects don't have a significant impact, orbits take the shape of conic sections: circles, ellipses, parabolas, and hyperbolas.  Parabolas are a infinitesimally precise boundary case between ellipses and hyperbolas are so aren't worth worrying about.  Circles are a similarly precise special case of ellipses.

[image: Open, closed, and suborbital paths]

If your satellite $S$ is in an approximately circular orbit (the blue path) around planet $P$ and a force acts on it, it might expand the ellipse (the green path).  Even more energy might push the orbit into an open hyperbola so that the satellite escapes from the planet (the red path).

If the force acts counter to the path of the orbit, it contracts, and if it contracts enough, it will pass through the planet (the yellow path).  Satellites can't generally pass through planets so such paths are more akin to normal falling as we are all familiar with it, and so are termed 'suborbital'.

It's also important to note that a quick application of force will only ever produce changes to the orbit that bring the satellite back to where it was (within the inertial frame of reference of the body being orbited) when the force was applied unless the orbit becomes open or suborbital.  So if the satellite is at 30,000 km and is given a knock, the new orbit will always include a point that is at 30,000 km

Escaping from a body that is itself orbiting another will generally put you on an elliptical orbit around that second body.  Escaping from the Earth will put you in an elliptical orbit around Sol.

A good way to get an intuitive sense for this is to play an orbital simulator game like Kerbal Space Program.

The amount of energy involved in significant orbit changes is immense, and if applied in in uncontrolled manner it would cause highly significant effects beyond orbital changes.  Consider that the energy to get a capsule with three humans in it to the moon and back is about equivalent to a city destroying nuclear weapon.  The energy involved in making changes to the moons orbit are literally astronomical.

So, in summary, it's best not to think about knocking something out of orbit but to think about changing the orbit enough to have whatever specific effect you are after, with the most extreme being to escape from a closed orbit, or to crash into whatever it's orbiting.

Comment: Blowing up a Saturn V would give you about 2 kilotons. While significant, that'd be a hell of a flimsy city.